# Custom textarea/contenteditable with divs inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, customization

I’ currently working on a website, where a user should be able to write and insert new songs with belonging chords into a database.
To sum things up, and get to the point pretty quick, here is my problem:

I have a div with the id “#textarea”, and the attribute contenteditable=“true”. On each enter/linebreak, I would like to create a new div with the class “.chords” and the attribute contenteditable=“false”. This ".chords" div should be placed right before the new line, like the image shows here:

[image: The red color is the #textarea div, and the blue color the .chords divs]
*The red color is the #textarea div, and the blue color the .chords divs*

So my question is: how do I do this?
I’ve posted the code I've tried in the end of this post, but as you see if you run it, the .chords divs are positioned below the new line, so I’m now a bit stuck.. If any of you guys have an idea on how to do this, please let me hear from you!

```js
$(function(e) {
  $('#textarea').keydown(function(e) {
    var i = 0;

    // Check if the returnkey is being pressed
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      $("#textarea div:last-of-type").after("<div class=\"chords\" id=\"" + (i + 1) + "\" contenteditable=\"false\"></div>");
      i = i + 1;
    }
  });
})
```

```css
#textarea {
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.chords {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

#textarea div:not(.chords) {
  margin-top: 20px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textarea" contenteditable="true">
  <div class="chords" id="1" contenteditable="false"></div>
  <div></div>
  <!--End of #textarea-->
</div>
```

Comment: I think you cannot do this because the text on the same div but another dynamic div are different. I think you need to find another way.

Comment: Hmm, you might be right. I'm studying at the education "webintegrator", so I'm not an expert yet..

Comment: I can help you different way

Comment: That would be nice. Do you have any suggestions on this, or something similar, could be done?

Comment: Yes Just wait a bit

Comment: I just created it can i post it as an answer...?

Comment: Okay, nice. Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: If you found your need please don't forget to accept the answer.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar Something like that

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #textarea {
          border: 1px solid red;
          line-height: 50px;
          font-size: 20px;
          min-height: 40px;
        }

        .chords {
          height: 30px;
          border: 1px solid black;
          position: relative;
          margin-top:5px;
        }

        #textarea div:not(.chords) {
          margin-top: 20px;
          min-height: 40px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(e) {
              $('#textarea').keydown(function(e) {
                var i = 0;

                // Check if the returnkey is being pressed
                if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                  $(this).after('<div class="chords" id="'+ (i + 1) +'" contenteditable="false"></div><div>'+$(this).html()+'</div>');
                  $(this).html("");
                  i = i + 1;
                }
              });
            })
        </script>
        <div id="textarea" contenteditable="true">
        </div>
          <div class="chords" id="1" contenteditable="false"></div>
          <div></div>
          <!--End of #textarea-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Check it out
https://jsfiddle.net/emarufhasan/66L2ohnp/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=66L2ohnp

Comment: Ah, I see what you did there. The idea behind is good, but my client thinks that it's important that it's like one big textarea, where you can write, delete and edit the text, and not just through one textfield. But thank you for your suggestion!